# Automation to open daily email link, fill form, click link to submit, download pdf and share

Tags: bash

My question is where to learn about automation? a book or a course that can help with my project. I'm trying to approach this issue, I'm getting daily email to fill a form that I need to download the confirmation  and then share with email:
Script for automating:

1. clicking a link in the email,
2. fill a form of two boxes and confirmation,
3. click submit,
4. download the pdf confirmation,
5. share the downloaded pdf via email.

I know there is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932205/automatizing-web-browser-form-filling-in-python

Comment: Links to external resources is off-topic; is there another way you can phrase your question?

Comment: @JeffSchaller the link discussed part of what I'm looking for (automation of filling). My question is where to learn about automation? a book or a course.

Comment: Requests for learning material are off-topic... https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks for tip!, where do you think should I ask such question? also how about where do I find the "find official documentation" for automation?

Comment: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/